# Loading database?

Tags: python, mysql, wxpython

my question is how can I do something while I connect to a MySQL database?
To make this clearer: Lets say I try to connect to a database:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "testhost",user ="testuser", passwd ="testpw", db = "testdb")
```

Well, thing is, generally, when the host isn't localhost, it usually takes up a bit to load and while this happens, the application "freezes" (I'm using wxPython). Now, what I want is, instead of "freezing", it would display something that represents "loading", it could be an image, a text, doesn't matter, instead of freezing. Also, what about splashscreens? As far as I tried, all I've managed to do is some splashscreens which disappear after X time and when I click on it. I really don't know how to take advantage of it to load resources and, for example, a MySQL database. The last time I tried to load up a MySQL database with splashscreen, it actually loaded up first, then it showed the splashscreen (lol).
Thanks.

Comment: btw, store you database settings in a configuration file instead of your program source code.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of that delay by using `skip-name-resolve` in your MySQL configuration and connecting to the server by IP address.  The connection should be nearly instant unless it's trying to resolve a hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, I came to an answer, a more concrete one for wxPython. I followed this simple example to make it work:

```
import wx
import thread
from time import sleep

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Ready")
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="Start")
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.label, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.btn, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.gauge, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, evt):
        self.btn.Enable(False)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)
        self.label.SetLabel("Running")
        thread.start_new_thread(self.longRunning, ())

    def onLongRunDone(self):
        self.gauge.SetValue(100)
        self.label.SetLabel("Done")
        self.btn.Enable(True)

    def longRunning(self):
        """This runs in a different thread.  Sleep is used to simulate a long running task."""
        sleep(3)
        wx.CallAfter(self.gauge.SetValue, 20)
        sleep(5)
        wx.CallAfter(self.gauge.SetValue, 50)
        sleep(1)
        wx.CallAfter(self.gauge.SetValue, 70)
        sleep(10)
        wx.CallAfter(self.onLongRunDone)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.TopWindow = MainFrame(None)
    app.TopWindow.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

From here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks , hope this helps :).

Answer (score 1):

If your program needs to do two things at once, then using multiple threads is a good way to do it. In your case, you have a GUI that you'd like to stay responsive, and you have a database to connect to. You need to do the database work in a separate thread, instead of on the thread that handles GUI events; that will keep the GUI working while the connection is being made. I'm afraid I can't tell you how to write multithreaded code in Python, but I think Google is your friend here.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed some idea to how I could do such thing, so I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1):

For examples of how to write multithreaded Python programs using the threading module, see

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/1/

and the official documentation:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Answer (score 1):

Threading would really help in this case 
Check this out : http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2010/08/30/easy-python-threading-mysql-connections/